# google api is known, but which account?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Someone in our company has created a google-map-api-key. We have the key, we can work with it, it works great. The problem is: We don't know, who has created the api-key? How can we find that?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Is this key related to your company's google-account or is it just some key you know and where you like to find the owner?

Comment: we have just some key and we would like to find the owner. The key was created one year ago and nobody can remember, who was the creator..

Comment: I'm afraid in this case you have to ask each colleague. It would violate the privacy when there would be a way to find the name of the creator

Comment: to ask each colleague = more than 1000 possibilities and not all of them is now here.. :'( This is a key for an online-game and key is currently deactivated and we don't know why?

Comment: Use blackboard, SMS, email...whatever. However, you should consider to follow Pat Dobson's suggestion, the keys used by your company should be under your company's control and nothing else.

Comment: It is mostly the case but sometimes there are some unexpected issues.

Comment: Intranet / Internal Memo / Company Newsletter etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case probably the best solution would be contacting google at https://google.secure.force.com/

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is rationlise your accounts and set up one 'master' account in your businesses name. It can be owned by someone but the login credentails should be available - although safe.
Then simply set up a new API key for your app and use that.

Comment: Unfortunately we have to find the api-key-creator in the company (> 1000 possibilities) and 3 colleagues are involved with this task..